# CKEditor is stripping a tags when copying and pasting from microsoft word. How can I diagnose why this is happening?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am tasked with fixing a problem with my company's CMS. We use CKEditor. When users cut from microsoft word and paste into the editor, tags are removed. This was done intentionally by someone who no longer works at the company, and now we want to allow `a` tags.

I am able to find the editor by going into the javascript console. When I inspect the object, I find that `editor.config.allowedContent` is set to `"p[*](*){*}; h1[*](*){*}; h2[*](*){*}; em; b; u; ul[*](*){*}; ol[*](*){*}; li[*](*){*}; img[*](*){*}; iframe[*](*){*}; a[*](*){*}; object[*](*){*}; param[*](*){*}; embed[*](*){*}; video[*](*){*}; i; table[*](*){*}; tr[*](*){*}; td[*](*){*}; script[*](*){*}; h3[*](*){*}; span[*](*){*}; br[*](*){*}; div[*](*){*}; strong; blockquote[*](*){*}` which contains an a tag.

What other possible causes could their be for the link tags being stripped on copy + paste?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];


config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
config.baseFloatZIndex = 100001;

config.extraAllowedContent = 'a';

};
CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

Furthermore it seems some config options are set dynamically:

```
this.editorObject = CKEDITOR.inline(this.$editable[0],{
            forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
            title: this.label,
            customConfig: '',
            removePlugins: 'autocorrect,format,stylescombo',
            removeButtons: 'PasteText,Flash,Anchor,ShowBlocks,About',
            extraPlugins: extraPlugins,
            linkShowAdvancedTab: false,
            linkShowTargetTab: true,
            youtube_responsive: true,
            youtube_related: false,
            scayt_autoStartup: true,
            readOnly: this.disabled,
            floatSpacePinnedOffsetY: 100,
            floatSpaceDockedOffsetY: 25,
            toolbar: this.toolbarDefinitions[this.variant],
            allowedContent: allowedContent,
            blockedKeystrokes: blockedKeystrokes,
            keystrokes: keystrokes,
            on: {
                instanceReady: _.bind(function(e) {
                    if (this.fieldname == 'inc_clean_text' && this.area) {
                        this.area.generateInlineVideoPlayers();
                        var area = this.area;
                        async.nextTick(function() {
                            _.each(area.inlineVideoPlayers, function(player) {
                                player.menu && player.menu.show();
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    this.$editable.focus();

                    // When triggerred will focus on the editor.
                    this.$editable.on('focusCursor', (function() {
                        var range = this.editorObject.createRange();
                        range.moveToElementEditablePosition(this.editorObject.editable(), true);
                        this.editorObject.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
                    }).bind(this));

                    if (this.editorObject.document.$.getElementById('caret-position-placeholder')) {
                        // When there is a caret placeholer present will put the cursor there and
                        // remove the placeholder element.
                        var node = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(this.editorObject.document.$.getElementById('caret-position-placeholder'));
                        var range = new CKEDITOR.dom.range(this.editorObject.document);
                        range.selectNodeContents(node);
                        this.editorObject.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
                        $(this.editorObject.document.$.getElementById('caret-position-placeholder')).remove();
                    }

                    if (this.$editable.hasClass('pancaption_override')) {
                        // ! TODO Move elsewhere.
                        // Code specific to the main feature image caption editor.
                        if (this.$editable.data('reshow')) {
                            this.$editable.data('reshow', false);
                            $('.pancaption_default').hide();
                            this.$editable.attr('contenteditable', true);
                            this.$editable.show().focus().trigger('click');
                            this.editorObject.setReadOnly(this.disabled);
                        }
                        if (this.$editable.html() == '') this.$editable.trigger('focusCursor');
                    }

                    // When on the new article page and clicking on a field with default text then empty
                    // the editable text.

                    //this.editorObject.setData('');
                    //this.$editable.trigger('focusCursor');
                    //this.$editable.toggleClass('empty', true);
                }, this),

                change: _.bind(this.contentChanged, this)
            }
        });
```

Let me know if I should trace any of these variables.

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using @Nick Manning?

Comment: Copy/pasting from word is likely (at least part of)  your issue. You need to run that text through a plaintext filter (I just paste into a .txt doc first to strip out all the Word garbage syntax. Otherwise you end up dumping extra MS Word hidden characters into your HTML doc.

Comment: @mrbubbles 4.5.4

Comment: @Korgrue it seems to automatically strip the garbage out. I'm trying to figure out why so that I can allow `a` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling which tags are allowed or disallowed is done through the `config.js` file usually located in the root of the CKEditor directory. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration

As you've discovered through the console you can either allow or disallow certain tags through `config.allowContent` or `config.disallowedContent` respectively. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf

Comment: My question is that it seems that `a` tags are allowed based on the config. However, they are stripped when I copy and paste. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Are you able to paste in the `config.js`? I think this may be key.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `config.js` file here?

Comment: I wonder if it's simpler to just go through the ckeditor object in the javascript console rather than look at the config file and try to determine what is overwritten where. But regardless, I included the config contents if that helps!

Comment: Great, would you be able to trace the value of the `allowedContent` variable in the `this.editorObject` object? Line 16 in the 2nd code block. :)

Also can you see where this is set?